# Is it worth to dynamically load JS file, or "defer" is enough

Tags: javascript, performance

- Let's assume that there is a page with a button.
- When button is clicked - dialog with map needs to show.
- Size of script that creates map dialog is 50kb gzipped.
- The button is not always clicked (like 15% of visits).

I need to include map script (JS file) without hurting page performance.

- First way: add `<script>` to footer with `defer` attribute.
- Second way: dynamically load JS file only after button is clicked (create `<script>` element, append it, wait for onload).

Which method should I use? If I use `defer` method - will parsing/execution of this JS file hurt performance (especially on mobile)?

Comment: If you do not need the script, then load it when needed

Comment: You could even start downloading `onhover` and save a few milliseconds

Comment: @mplungjan I'd prefer to not have delay at all (between "click" and "open dialog"), is loading large JS file that might not always be used considered bad practice? Because of memory usage and JS execution time?

Comment: @Marvin3 maybe display a "Please wait" notification while loading the script "When needed" if the delay is that much of a worry then I would say it would be an issue to load it even if it isn't being used. It will use unnecessary resources and delay page loading for no reason.